# Установка ватермарка на gif

Tags: php, изображения

Не могу разобраться как установить ватермарк на `gif` анимацию.
Сам ватермарк ставится, но при этом сама анимация пропадает. Следующий код:

```
    $source_src = 'cats.gif'; 
    $params = getimagesize($source_src);
    $source = imagecreatefromgif($source_src);

    $max_size = 730;

    $resource = $source;
    $ww = $params[0];
    $hw = $params[1];

    $namephoto = 'newcats.gif';

    $end = 'gif';
    $posx = $ww - 70;
    $posy = $hw - 5;
    $color = imagecolorallocate($resource, 225,225,225);

    imagettftext ($resource, 8, 0, $posx, $posy, $color, 'arial.ttf', 'Hello');
    imagegif($resource, 'gif/'.$namephoto.'.'.$end, 100);
    imagejpeg($resource, 'preview/'.$namephoto.'.'.$end, 100);
    imagedestroy($resource);
```

Я так понял, `imagecreatefromgif` создает изображение с 1ого кадра. Возможно ли найти решение этой проблемы?

Comment: Ну сделать можно всё. Видимо желательно без извратов. Посмотрите пакет ImageMagic. http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php , в примере 5 показан ресайзинг всех фреймов анимированного gif'а. 

Правда наложение текста на каждый фрейм может заметно увеличить размер gif'а.

Comment: Хотел через ImageMagic, но он не установлен на хостинге (пишет не найден этот класс). 
Возможно есть какой то извращенный способ получения кода гифки и его разбивания на кадры и дальнейшее нанесения ватермарка на кадр и после его обратная сборка? Хотя тут скорее по скорости будет все очень плохо...

Comment: Парсинг gif на нижнем уровне, как на C. На php.net в комментариях для определения анимированных gif'ов используют регэкспы, находя несколько раз "волшебные" последовательности байт...

Comment: Заглянул на php.net :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php Комментарий fezber at yamasoft dot com

Ссылка на его модуль http://www.yamasoft.com/php-gif.zip . Увы, ссылка не рабочая. Правда гугл даёт много разных ссылок...

Comment: Спасиб. Вот рабочая http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/index.php?source=phpthumb.gif.php
Буду разбираться, смотреть. Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Там много разных. Правда задача, как правило другая -- ресайзинг, но это уже другой вопрос -- изменение размера или комбинация с водяными (знаками)

Успехов.